# Enumerate all SomeClass<T> objects of all T

Tags: c++, events, templates

I have `Event<T>` class for event handle, where `T` is functor type of signature `void (*)()` (or some class-based closure).

In code below omitted ctor copies constructed object to map `events`.

```
template <class T>
class Event
{
    ...
    T action;
    long explode;
    static map<string, Event> events;
    ...
    void shot()
    {
        action();
    }
    ...
    static void check()
    {
        // foreach pair in events
        if (itsATimeFor(pair->second.explode))
            pair->second.shot();
    }
};
```

The `check()` function tests if any event has fire in its hole and shots on success.

Current realization has some major faults: it tests only one type of event per call and therefore is useless

The question is, how to enumerate all events from all instantiated `Event<T>` classes?

Comment: It seems you are building your own event-handling system. Have you considered using [Boost.Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/signals.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a common base class, which means you can store all of these things in a collection.  To do this, you'll have to get rid of the `static` stuff, but I don't see that as an issue really.

```
class IEvent
{
public:
    virtual ~IEvent() = 0  { };
    virtual void check() = 0;
};  // eo interface IEvent


template<class T>
class Event : public IEvent
{
public:
    virtual ~Event()
    {
    }; // eo dtor

    void check()
    {
    };
};  // eo class Event
```

Now you can instantiate your Event class as you want and put them in a collection.  And with that, you can enumerate them and call `check()` on each instance.  I see no reason for you to be using `static` here.  I can help remove those statics if you feel you've had to put them there for a reason.

Comment: I already done like you wrote at the moment. I prefer using collections here, so in my version base is abstract with ctor including it in collection and dtor excluding and of course, the `virtual void shot() = 0` and the `static void pullTheTrigger()`.